# Runs fine from Flash Drive but not when installed. PLEASE HELP!

Tags: system-installation

Hey guys I have an issue here with installing ubuntu and pear OS. I have tried both from my usb and they both work fine off the flash drive. I installed them on my laptop and every time on  both ubuntu and Pear OS I get to the log in screen and on Pear OS the screen is half black and I can't see any button or anything, and its pretty much the same thing with ubuntu. I have tried reinstalling them a few times recommended setting, I also tried formatting the hard drive and all that good stuff but I keep getting the same issue. My laptop is a "HP Probook 6455b". I had no issues installing ubuntu on my mac so I have installed in the past fine but I really want it on my laptop. Any help would be much appreciated! Please be clear on instructions because while I consider my self to be good with computer and stuff I don't really know linux very well, just mac and windows.

Comment: Pear OS is not supported here. Please rewrite your question as it pertains to Ubuntu as you are more likely to get an answer. Thank you!